# Google Tag Manager tag creation requirements

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I just created a new tag on one of my Google Analytics accounts.  That generated a new Google Analytics tracking code.  So because this property has a different tracking code does this now mean I have to create a new Google Analytics Universal tag in the associated Google Tag Manager account with the tracking code for the new Google Analytics property if I want to track anything?